# Created an onclick function to remove data from a line chart in ChartsJs, but getting "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart

I was able to create a line chart with static data. Now, I am trying to create an onclick function that when you click, all the static data will be removed from the chart.  I followed the [documentation](https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/f5tazexg/36/) for chartsjs, but unfortunately it is not working. I am getting the following error:  **Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"**. I find this odd because my data is defined as you can see below.

This is my first time working with charts and chartsjs, so any guidance is appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is my [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/f5tazexg/36/) on JSFiddle

In my html, I added the onclick while you can see my removeData function.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
<button onclick="removeData()">Remove Data</button>
```

Here is my JS.  You can see my removeData function.

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478],
        label: "Jonnies Pizza",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Pizza Sales Worldwide'
    }
  }
});



function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `removeData()` function expects a `chart` object but you don't provide it in `button onClick`.

You can change your code as follows and it will work.

```
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478],
        label: "Jonnies Pizza",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Pizza Sales Worldwide'
    }
  }
});      

function removeData() {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.pop();
    chart.update();
}
```

Please have a look at your amended [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfhum1dg/).

Comment: @csb00: I updated my answer and hope this helps now.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I passed chart in the button onclick, created  made the chart a variable and it was working.  Thank you!

Comment: Why did you remove the forEach loop? I figured if you're going to be removing data, you have to loop through it.

Comment: @csb00: I got rid of the `forEach` loop because your chart contains a single dataset. But the code should also work with your initial `forEach` loop.